# Django bug : ImproperlyConfigured at /databrowse/ . How to solve this bug?

Tags: django

My urls.py of the project looks like this

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib import databrowse

from world.views import welcome
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', welcome),
    (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^databrowse/', include(databrowse.site.root)),
)


urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/$',include('django.views.static.serve'),{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True})
    )
```

What changes have to be done for this to work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only change you have to make is to follow the actual [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/databrowse/). The documentation doesn't use `include` for databrowse.